# Svelte Transition Direction Switch Issue

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I'm using an `each` block to iterate over an array of items, and an `if` block inside that to check which of the items should be shown, and a `fly` transition is applied to the inner items with a variable that controls the direction of the transition so that if the user hits next everything goes out to and comes in from <-- this way and if they hit previous button everything goes out to and comes in from --> this way.

It works great, with one exception. When the user is going in one direction and then they click the other direction the out animation for the currently shown item goes the wrong direction but only on the first out animation and then it falls in line. Here's a REPL of the issue: https://svelte.dev/repl/1aa3608458f84a4fb4d93b10b47ae3f1?version=3.25.0

Is there any way to make the first outro animation go the right way after a direction change? I feel like there's something I'm not seeing.

**Edit:**

There is a [Github](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/5244) issue which seems somewhat related to this issue.

As I noted in the Github issue it seems that the behavior only affects items inside of an `each` block. This [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/61d774c051d24eb79070066835cbf7db?version=3.25.0) shows the behavior working as expected with dynamic x directions.

I came up with [this workaround](https://svelte.dev/repl/eb47ab82f9f348e39062c5d4815bdea2?version=3.25.0) where I move the transition to a parent element of the `each` block and duplicate it, then alternate which `each` block is shown.

I would love to find out if there is a better workaround since the duplication is painful. If not I'll just make it a component and hide it away in shame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the reason for this behavior is that you define ‘out’ function before you know the direction in which ‘out’ is going hence the wrong direction if you change direction.
You can define your own function for ‘out’ and it’s run when you select the direction and therefore you have the correct direction available in your own function.
I’m not sure is my explanation correct but here is working example:

```
const myOut=(el)=>{
  return fly(el,{x:-x, duration:600})
}
```

And in div:

```
out:myOut|local
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't know that it quite relates to the actual problem I'm having. I added new info to the question, it seems that this only happens inside each blocks for some strange reason.

Comment: You’re right, it seems to be a problem related to `each`. My solution seems to work and I believe it’s due to somehow forcing `x` to be updated to correct value when `out` is about to run.

Comment: Wow, your solution does work. Sorry, I didn't give it a shot until just now. I even went and made an entire component to switch between 2 identical slots.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. I didn’t find the way to access animation parameters from `outrostart`. I believe `outrostart` would be the perfect time to change animation properties just before `out` starts.

Answer (score 0):

The position absolute fix with the intransit class that is added and removed on outrostart and outroend didn't work properly for me.

So I took the solution from @grohjy and tweaked the original REPL so that it uses grid layout to put the two elements that are transitioning in and out into the same space:
https://svelte.dev/repl/5613ab81aa2349bb92f356b0fdc786d0?version=4.2.9

I also added a few other tweaks of my own e.g. making the solution robust to width changes.